# How can I know if Apache Spark is the right tool?

Tags: apache-spark

Just wondering, is there somewhere a list of questions to ask ourselves in order to know whether Spark is the right tool or not ?

Once again I spent part of the week implementing a POC with Apache Spark in order to compare the performance against pure python code and I was baffled when I saw the 1/100 ratio (in favor of python).

I know that Spark is a "big data" tool and everyone keeps saying "Spark is the right tool to process TB/PB of data" but I think that is not the only thing to take into account.

In brief, my question is, when given small data as input, how can I know if the computing will be consuming enough so that Spark can actually improve things ?

Comment: If the data it small, spark is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is such a list, but if there was, the first question would probably be

> Does your data fit on a single machine?

And if the answer is 'Yes', you do not need Spark.

Spark is designed to process lots of data such that it cannot be handled by a single machine, as an alternative to Hadoop, in a fault-tolerant manner.

There are lots of overheads, such as fault-tolerance and network, associated with operating in a distributed manner that cause the apparent slow-down when compared to traditional tools on a single machine.

Because Spark *can* be used as a parallel processing framework on a small dataset, does not mean that it should be used in such a way. You will get faster results and less complexity by using, say, Python, and parallelizing your processing using threads.

Spark excels when you have to process a dataset that does not fit onto a single machine, when the processing is complex and time-consuming and the probability of encountering an infrastructure issue is high enough and a failure would result in starting again from scratch.

Comparing Spark to native Python is like comparing a locomotive to a bicycle. A bicycle is fast and agile, until you need to transport several tonnes of steel from one end of the country to the other: then - not so fun.

Comment: You say that if my data fits on a single machine then Spark is not the right tool. But what if, for example, I have to do billions of calculation on that small data. In that case, would spark be useful ?

Comment: Good question, I was focusing purely on speed. In that scenario the main benefit Spark can bring is fault tolerance. Even then it would depend on the nature of the calculations, i.e. can the processing be broken down into checkpoints from which to restart in the event of a failure. From what you have said in your question and comment, it feels to me like Spark would be a premature optimisation.

Comment: Yeah, fault tolerance is not really needed in my case. Speed was the main goal but it seems that there isn't nearly enough calculations for Spark to be worth it

Comment: Spark gets a lot of hype and looks great on a CV, but the question shouldn't be 'can I use spark for this' and should be 'what's the simplest way to solve this problem', and sometimes, Spark is indeed the answer.